# How to access bricked phone /system folder? Fix corrupted file

Tags: adb, 4.3-jelly-bean, recovery-mode

I have a SK504, brazilian phone. Well, i was trying to change my boot animation, but downloaded and installed a corrupted one.
So, when i rebooted, the phone shows ANDROID like always, but after, a black screen appears and stays forever.
I can acess recovery, and the phone is rooted. No backup. Is there a way to get into the phone trough USB and change the bootanimation.zip file to a valid one? Because i don't want to reset it or install another ROM, unless necessary.

Besides the corrupted bootanimation.zip file, i have two more on the /system/media folder, they are bootanimation.old (the original one) and bootanimation(2).zip, a valid one that worked before, so there is no need to transfer something from pc to phone, just rename the files.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

On custom recoveries (CWM, TWRP) you normally are able to use adb. With that you can delete the corrupted bootanimation and replace it with your original one.

- Mount your /system partition using "Mount->System" on TWRP or "Mounts and Storage->mount /system" on CWM
- Plug your phone onto the computer
- Remove your corrupt bootanimation: `adb shell "rm /system/media/bootanimation.zip"`
- Restore your old bootanimation: `adb shell "mv /system/media/bootanimation.old /system/media/bootanimation.zip"`
- You may have to set the right permissions: `adb shell "chmod 0644 /system/media/bootanimation.zip`

Comment: Well this is another problem, i have the stock recovery, without "install from zip" or any other options that should help. I tried "install update from an external storage",using an android explorer named Aroma, but always get "Installation Aborted."

Comment: @LucasSoares then you should install a custom recovery from fastboot mode and then follow the steps in this answer.

Comment: You say that like it's so easy, but if you have a phone with no custom recoveries available online, that's practically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an extremely simple solution which is sort of cheating but functional nonetheless.

Step 1: Extract the contents of the custom recovery (here CWM) to a folder (eg. `SOMENAME`.

Step 2: Go to `META-INF\com\google\android`.

Step 3: Open the file `updater-script`.

Step 4: Where you find the indeterminate.png files being deleted and extracted, paste the following two lines between the above mentioned lines:
`delete("system/media/bootanimation.zip");
package_extract_file("system/media/bootanimation.old", "system/media/bootanimation.zip");`
Step 5: Save the file and exit.
Step 6: Now zip the contents of `SOMENAME` to create a new flashable zip file `SOMENAME.zip`.
Step 7: Save this file in the SD card and flash it in your phone.
Step 8: Normal Clockwork Recovery Mod will open, but the required copying of the `bootanimation` file has been executed while opening.